# Finding out all entries made in a specific hour mysql

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I am looking for a mysql query that will return all the entries made in the same hour even if the date is different. The column type is timestamp. I searched several other stackoverflow posts but could not find the solution. Can this be done and if so how.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `HOUR` function ([doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour))

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE HOUR(time_from) = 10
```

Additional examples: [MySQL HOUR() function](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-hour-function.php)